# C# creating callbacks playback finished

Tags: c#, callback

C# 2008 SP1

I am using the following code to record, play, and stop save the recording. Everything works fine. However, I would like to add a call back that will fire when the playback has finished.

I am P/Invoke using the winmm.dll library.

Many thanks for any advice.

```
public partial class SoundTest : Form
    {
        const uint SND_ASYNC = 0x0001;
        const uint SND_FILENAME = 0x00020000;
        const uint SND_NODEFAULT = 0x0002;

        [DllImport("winmm.dll")]
        private static extern int mciSendString(string lpstrCommand, string lpstrReturnString, 
                                                int returnLength, int hwndCallBack);

        [DllImport("winmm.dll")]
        private static extern bool PlaySound(string pszsound, UIntPtr hmod, uint fdwSound);

        public SoundTest()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Disable stop button
            this.btnSaveStop.Enabled = false;
        }

        private void btnRecord_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Disable play and record button
            this.btnRecord.Enabled = false;
            this.btnPlay.Enabled = false;
            // Enable stop button
            this.btnSaveStop.Enabled = true;

            // Record from microphone
            mciSendString("Open new Type waveaudio Alias recsound", "", 0, 0);
            mciSendString("record recsound", "", 0, 0);     
        }

        private void btnSaveStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Enable play and record
            this.btnRecord.Enabled = true;
            this.btnPlay.Enabled = true;
            // Disable Stop button
            this.btnSaveStop.Enabled = false;
            mciSendString("save recsound c:\\record.wav", "", 0, 0);
            mciSendString("close recsound ", "", 0, 0);
        }

        private void btnPlay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //// Diable record button while playing back
            //this.btnRecord.Enabled = false;
            PlaySound("c:\\record.wav", UIntPtr.Zero, SND_ASYNC | SND_FILENAME | SND_NODEFAULT);   
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, the only way you will be able to do this is by calling a callbackfunction yourself right after you call the PlaySound API function and passing a 
SND_SYNC parameter instead of SND_ASYNC.

```
private void btnPlay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //// Disable record button while playing back
    //this.btnRecord.Enabled = false;
    PlaySound("c:\\record.wav", UIntPtr.Zero, SND_SYNC | SND_FILENAME | SND_NODEFAULT);   

    //write your callback code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The 'callback' from MCI is actually a windows message. If you pass the handle of your form as the hwndcallback and override the WndProc you can handle the message.

There's some more information on the WndProc [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/25fb51ec-4198-4554-8215-742694a480f1), and a 64-bit friendly dllimport specification [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/gametechnologiesaudioxact/thread/c6b79853-07c2-4382-9826-6932b958142b).